# Any suggestions for an interactive map application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, maps, openmap

I need to do something similar to this:

[Flash-based interactive map](http://www.mapsofworld.com/world-map-viewer.html)

I wonder if you could recommend a good library or something.  JQuery or Javascript will be nice, but Flash/Action Script is not a good option.

Comment: http://www.giscloud.com/blog/gis-cloud-starts-html5-mapping-revolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery based solution for that - [jVectorMap](http://jvectormap.com).

Answer (score 0):

Give the Google maps API to make your own custom map from your own images

http://forevermore.net/articles/photo-zoom/

http://www.maplib.net/

You can then use the same api to detect clicks that would trigger modal windows.

Answer (score 0):

**You can have a variety of 44 Maping APIs [HERE](http://blog.programmableweb.com/2007/05/30/44-mapping-apis/)**

and of course Flash/Action Script is not a good option since it takes much resource and is always slower than JavaScript and AJAX based solutions.

**[HERE](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/yourfirstmap)** is your first tutorial to set up your map (from Google developers).

and finally, **[HERE](http://www.esri.com/mapping-for-everyone/index.html)** is a collection of Free Mapping Tools for creating maps online.

Hope this helps :)